# Magento and Wordpress with Fishpig extension giving 404 when moved to localhost

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I had the Fishpig extension installed on a live magento site with wordpress blog all working fine. Wordpress is installed in magento/wp/ and is displaying as magento/blog/

I wanted to move the site to test server to develop offline. I moved the database and files, using mamp and updated:

magento db web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url

/app/etc/local.xml with db details

wp_options change siteurl and home

The homepage of magento is loading, but /admin/ is just giving a 404. The /wp/ is loading but just the site title is displayed, not the content or the magento theme. The wordpress admin is working, but /blog/ is giving a 404.

Ive read other related threads. I think all files have correct permissions and databases must be connecting. I'm thinking this must be down to fishpig, are there some setting for that i need to change, or maybe the .htaccess is messing things up?

I dont seem to have anything in var/log

Comment: Have you changed the database details in wordpress configuration file i.e "magento/wp/wp-config.php" ?

Comment: Yes, I changed that. Admin section of WordPress is working fine. I think all my database connections are working.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking throught the .htaccess file in the root of my local site and found this block

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I commented it out and everything started working. Its the block that is in the /wp/ directory .htaccess file. I have no idea how it found its was into the root file - but this seems to have been the problem.